# How to move local Git repository (with history) to be managed by Gitosis on remote server?

Tags: git, gitosis

I'm switching from SVN to Git with Gitosis installed on a central server for centralized repositories on Ubuntu server.

I have had all my SVN repositories moved and initiated into new Git repositories, and also had all history moved to Git.

Now that I have all the repositories migrated to Git, I want to add all the repositories into Gitosis to be managed by Gitosis.

How can I move the repositories (Git initiated ones) into Gitosis `/srv/gitosis/repositories` and manage them through `gitosis-admin.git` remotely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to declare you repo in the `conf/gitosis.conf` file from your gitosis-admin local (cloned) repo:

```
[group groupname]
writable = reponame
members = username

git add -A
git ci -m "updated configuration"
git push
```

, which will create a bare repo, to which to which you can push your local repo.

```
mkdir myproject
cd mypyroject
git init
# do some work, git add and commit files
# Then add your server as a remote and push:

git remote add serveralias git@hostname:reponame.git
git push serveralias master
```

See [this tutorial for more](http://kris.me.uk/2009/12/31/git-repository-server.html)

---

That being said, I find **[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)** much more complete than gitosis, like all those recent blog posts illustrate:

- [A Pure Git Deploy Workflow (with Jekyll and Gitolite)](http://blog.zerosum.org/2010/11/01/pure-git-deploy-workflow.html)
- [Git Repository Server using Gitolite](http://kris.me.uk/2010/09/30/git-repository-server-gitolite.html)
- [Gitolite installation with gitweb and anongit in Gentoo and Debian](http://blog.tampakrap.gr/gitolite-installation-with-gitweb-and-anongit-in-gentoo-and-debian/)

And you can migrate from [gitosis to gitolite easily enough](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/migrate.mkd).

Comment: But does this maintain the history once moved to Gitosis?

Comment: @doublethink: sure, you are pushing the all history. You can make a `git push --mirror` at first (only at first) to be extra sure. (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[git]+push+mirror)

Comment: Hm, on second thought, I think I'd better let you sort out your gitolite vs gitosis thing - "gitolite much more complete than gitolite", and is that a gitosis config?

Comment: @Jefromi: fixed. I was looking at both gitosis and gitolite config files when writing this answer, which helps explain the inversion. The main part of this answer is about gitosis.

Comment: Cool; I was pretty sure that was it, but didn't want to mess anything up!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this tutorial for managing gitosis repositories if you have successfully installed it:

http://fclose.com/b/1434/managing-repositories-on-git-server-using-gitosis/

Most of the normal management work (Add new administrator, Create a new user, Create a new repository, etc) can be done on administrator's side by editing and pushing gitosis-admin repository. You need to login to the gitosis server to do other things like adding hook script to send email automatically when somebody pushes, etc.